# Changing default search directories of fopen() in C

Tags: c, file-io, io, fopen

In which directory does the function fopen() look for the specified file?

**EDIT**

1. I use linux.
2. Is it possible to change, i.e.add/remove directories, in which the the function looks for the specified file?

Comment: Start your research with "current working directory".

Comment: You might also try `man getcwd`, if you're on a Linux/UNIX system.

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the environment(or the OS,if any) That  is the reason why the pathname is a string. C was disigned without any  I/O: all the I/O is in thelibraries, (which are implemented specifically for the target platform)

Comment: If you pass an absolute path, the directory thusly specified. ;-)

Comment: For instance: in DEC VMS, the filename could include versions, which were appended to the pathname in the C interface) And DOS/Windows of course still has these silly drive-letters....

Comment: Call `chdir` to change current dir.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that what I am trying to achieve can be done by changing the environment variables.

Answer (score -2):

If using visual studio.. the same folder as your dll.  If using unix... the current working directory.

Comment: for abs path.. fopen( "C:\\etc\\file.txt", "r" )